# Посчитать количество букв

Tags: python, count

Пользователь вводит список любых букв а программа считает сколько в том, что ввёл пользователь гласных букв. Цикл `for` использовать нельзя.

Код который пробовал я:

```
a = [str(i) for i in input("Введіть необмежену кількість літер Українського алфавіту: ").split()]

g = ["а", "о", "у", "е", "є", "і", "ї", "ю", "я", "А", "О", "У", "Е", "Є", "і", "Ї", "Ю", "Я"]
b=a.count(g)
print(b)
```

В итоге всегда пишет **0**.

Comment: for нельзя, а что можно? map, lambda, sum можно? (это почти готовый ответ)

Comment: Пишет 0, потому что в ``a`` список ``g`` не встречается ни разу.

Comment: ``str(i) for i in`` - аяяяй! ``for`` использовать нельзя!

Comment: Программа считает только гласные ?

Comment: и удалите свои ответы пожалуйста )!

Comment: Кстати, букву "и" куда-то дели, это же тоже гласная

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
count = len(list(filter(lambda letter: letter in 'аеиоуюя', text)))
```

вот так через lambda можно сделать)

Answer (score 2):

Через `map` применяем лямбду к каждой букве, получается набор значений `True` и `False`, потом их суммируем (`True` эквивалентно 1, `False` эквивалентно 0, так получим количество гласных)

```
count = sum(map(lambda letter: letter in "аоуеєіїиюя", text.lower()))
```

Comment: через map отлично